# Express Auth Middleware with Angular

Tags: angular, express

I'm creating an app that uses an Http interceptor for authentication in Angular, and auth middleware in ExpressJS. The interceptor and auth middleware works when I navigate to a route through the app, but not when I hit it directly through the URL. When I hit the route directly, I get the 'invalid grant' response from the server.

I wanted the auth middleware to apply to several routes, so I wrote it before the routes I want to authenticate.

```
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, distDir)));

router.use('/auth', require('./auth/authRoutes'));

router.use([auth.checkTokens, auth.verifyTokens.verifyUserToken]);

router.use('/users', require('./user/userRoutes'));

router.use('/courses', require('./course/courseRoutes'));

router.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, distDir + '/index.html'));
})
```

My check tokens method looks for the token that was passed in the header:

```
exports.checkTokens = (req, res, next) => {
    const userToken = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (userToken) {
        req.access_token = userToken;
        next();
    } else {
        return res.status(400).send({ auth: false, error: 'Invalid grant' });    
    }
}
```

The token is stored in local storage, which is then attached in the Http interceptor before the request is sent from the front-end.

Is this the correct implementation? I wanted to use local storage to test my interceptor's functionality easily. Would storing the token in a cookie resolve my particular issue?

**-- UPDATE --**

The route I'm trying to navigate is 'api/courses'. I'm able to get the authentication working when I click on a link through the app, but not when I type the address directly to the URL address bar. I want to be able to authenticate a user even if they type the URL to the address bar directly.

Here is my courses component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.less']
})
export class CoursesComponent extends HttpService implements OnInit {
  courses: Course[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
      super(http, httpErrorHandler, 'JWTService')
    this.courses = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCourses().subscribe((data: Course[]) => {
      this.courses = data;
    });
  }

  private getCourses(): Observable<Course[]> {
    return super.get<Course[]>('courses', this.courses, 'get courses')
  }
}
```

And I have an auth guard set up in the routes:

```
export const HomeRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'user-settings', 
        component: UserSettingsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'courses',
        component: CoursesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'course-form',
        component: CourseFormComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
  ];
```

This is my auth guard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
      // logged in so return true
      return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/auth/login'], { queryParams: {} });
    // this.router.navigate(['/auth'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is my interceptor class in Angular:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefreshingToken = false;
  private accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  tokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  oldToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private http: HttpClient) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = this.addToken(request, this.accessToken);
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error)
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          switch((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
            case 400:
            // console.log('handling 400 error')
              return this.handle400Error(error);
            case 401: 
            // console.log('handling 401 error')
              this.authService.refresh().subscribe((data: { access_token: string, refresh_token: string}) => {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token)
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh_token)
              })
              return this.handle401Error(request, next);
          }
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private handle400Error(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (error && error.status === 400 && error.error && error.error.error === 'invalid_grant') {
      // If we get a 400 and the error message is 'invalid_grant', the token is no longer valid so logout.
      return this.logoutUser();
    }
    return throwError(error);
  }

  private logoutUser() {
    this.authService.logout()
    return throwError('Error. Logged out user.')
  }

  private handle401Error(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.isRefreshingToken) {
      this.isRefreshingToken = true;

      // Reset here so that the following requests wait until the token
      // comes back from the refreshToken call.
      this.tokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((newToken: string) => {
          newToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
          if (newToken) {
            this.tokenSubject.next(newToken);
            if (this.oldToken === newToken) {
              return this.logoutUser();
            } else {
              return next.handle(this.addToken(req, newToken));
            }
          }

          // If we don't get a new token, we are in trouble so logout.
          return this.logoutUser();
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          // If there is an exception calling 'refreshToken', bad news so logout.
          return this.logoutUser();
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.isRefreshingToken = false;
        })
      );
    } else {
      return this.tokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(token => {
          return next.handle(this.addToken(req, token));
        })
      )
    }
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, access_token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer: ${access_token}`
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Using localStorage is better than using cookie, for security. But you have to add the data manually to the request (You can do this in interceptor). The above code looks fine, please post the HttpInterceptor Code from your angular and few details of what route you are hitting directly.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I updated my post